# What does it mean: event loop will continue running as long as the timer is active

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

What do these statements mean? From here https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_immediate_unref

> *By default, when an immediate is scheduled, the Node.js **event loop will continue running as long as the immediate is active.***

and

> *By default, when a timer is scheduled using either setTimeout() or setInterval(), the Node.js **event loop will continue running as long as the timer is active.***

What exactly does that mean?

> event loop **exit** / **not exit**

Exit how? Node.js process will stay alive until scheduled timer event will happen?

Answer (score 0):

> Node.js process will stay alive until scheduled timer event will happen?

Yes. When Node's event loop terminates, the process terminates. Active timers will prevent that from happening (until they run).